# CSS Grid not working. Neither the code shows up when I inspect in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

No grid functionality is shown in the browser. When I inspected, the css was not visible in inspect window also.(I wasn't visible. I am not saying visible but strikethrough)
Html and Css:-

```css
.genre-grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-gap: 1%;
    height: 100px;
}

.genre-grid img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="genre-grid">
                <div>Some Text</div>
                <div>
                    <img src="Assets/album-covers/fighter.png">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="Assets/album-covers/fighter.png">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="Assets/album-covers/fighter.png">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="Assets/album-covers/fighter.png">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="Assets/album-covers/fighter.png">
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it seems to be fine here

Comment: @TemaniAfif  I dont know why all images are stacked vertically even after using proper css for grid

Comment: because you have set 6 columns and 1 line, so horizontal construction turns out

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov should I remove grid-template-rows?

Comment: @Sigmax, what markup do you want in the end?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I want my some text to take 2fr and rest 5 images to take 1fr each in a 100px height div